# Telling the difference using Bernoulli tests

Tags: probability

I expect this is at the straightforward end of the spectrum, but I can't find anything using google. My need is for the maths that will hopefully emerge from this question, rather than to answer the question itself.

Suppose you are told that there are two different coins. One is completely fair, and so when tossed produces heads with a probability of exactly 50%. The other is biased, and produces heads with a probability of exactly 45%. If one of these coins is tossed N times, and you are provided with the outcome each time, how large must N be before you can be 95% confident which coin was being tossed?

Follow-up: if one person is tossing the unbiased coin, and someone else is tossing the biased coin, and you are provided with all the outcomes in both cases, what would N need to be so that you can identify who is tossing which coin (N is the same for both people) with 95% confidence? Intuitively I imagine that N would be smaller in this case, because there is more information. But with probability being so full of paradox, I am not sure about that!

I considered constructing 95% binomial confidence limits as a function of N in both cases, with the criterion that the lower limit of the unbiased coin must be greater than the upper limit of the biased coin, but I don't think that is the correct approach.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: $100000$th question of probability

Comment: There are two problems with your question. a) How confident you can be depends on the results, so you can't just ask "how large must $N$ be?". You could ask something like "What's the expected number of tosses required to reach a certain level of confidence?". b) It's not clear what exactly you mean by being $95\%$ confident which coin was tossed. In the standard framework, one tests a hypothesis against a null hypothesis and rejects the null hypothesis with a certain confidence based on the data – but here you have two hypotheses that play symmetric roles.

Comment: This might be better treated within the so-called Bayesian framework, but there you need to assign prior probabilities to the hypotheses. In the present case, you might want to consider the two hypotheses equally likely *a priori* and then ask how many times you need to toss the coin(s) *on average* in order to reach an *a posteriori* probability of $95\%$ for one of the hypotheses.

Comment: Thanks, your comments have helped me to rethink things.  My framing of the question was somewhat woolly, which I realised as soon as I tried writing a Python script to emulate the situation. What I meant by 95% confident was that the expected value for the probability of deducing the coin correctly is 0.95. So, if I conduct 1000 tests in which the coin is tossed N times, I will guess the coin correctly 950 times. I found that N depends on the threshold used to decide which coin was being tossed ... see next post.

Comment: Setting the threshold to the mean value of 45% and 50% worked fine. By using the binomial confidence interval expression I estimate N to give 95% confidence. This overpredicts N, which I think is to do with the idea that things only go wrong in terms of guessing the coin if the biased coin produces too many heads, or if it happens to be the unbiased coin, too few. I found that I got exactly the right N by dividing by root(2).

Comment: I am not sure how this translates into standard mathematical frameworks, but since I am an engineer, and it works (I will try it out for other scenarios, in particular the one that I need it for) I will leave it to anyone who is interested in this problem to work out the maths!